# Bind Gridview on Treeview Node Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, treeview

I want to bind gridview on treenode click.code works fine without error but in UI nothing changes, but when I use same code on button click, Gridview binds data properly.

My apsx code is

```
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                    <div style="overflow: scroll; height: 450px;">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TreeView ID="Folder_Treeview" runat="server" ShowLines="true" LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="childnode"
                                    Style="" ForeColor="Blue" SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="Green" OnSelectedNodeChanged="Folder_Treeview_SelectedItemChanged">
                                </asp:TreeView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="grid" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true"
                        PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                        runat="server">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Length">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLen" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Length")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Extention">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblFileType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Extension")%>'>
                                    </asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Creation Date & Time">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CreationTime")%>'>
                                    </asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <p>
                        <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
```

CS Code:

```
protected void Folder_Treeview_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = this.Folder_Treeview.SelectedNode;
        SetFolderPath(node);
    }

    public void SetFolderPath(TreeNode node)
    {        
        Session["ParentFolderId"] = node;
        //  System.IO.DirectoryInfo RootDir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/"));
        string CurrNode = node.Text;
        string separator = "\\";
        Folder_Treeview.PathSeparator = Convert.ToChar(separator);

        while (node.Parent != null)
        {
            CurrNode = node.Parent.Text + this.Folder_Treeview.PathSeparator + CurrNode;
            node = node.Parent;
        }
        ViewState["Folder"] = CurrNode;
        ViewState["FileType"] = "All";
        GetFilesFromFolder();
    }

private void GetFilesFromFolder()
    {
        // GET A LIST OF FILES FROM A SPECIFILED FOLDER.
        DirectoryInfo objDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath((string)ViewState["Folder"]));

        FileInfo[] listfiles = objDir.GetFiles("*." + ((string)ViewState["FileType"] != "All" ?
            ViewState["FileType"] : "*"));

        if (listfiles.Length > 0)
        {
            // BIND THE LIST OF FILES (IF ANY) WITH GRIDVIEW.
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = listfiles;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            lblMsg.Text = listfiles.Length + " files found";
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            lblMsg.Text = "No files found";
        }
    }
```

`OnSelectedNodeChanged` method get called on `node` click, and all value sets properly but never get reflect.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's your update panel.  The node event originates within the UpdatePanel so only the Update panel will get updated after postback.  Keep in mind that the full Page lifecycle occurs, so the gridview does get databound, but only the content within the UpdatePanel will be refreshed.

Your options:

1. Add `Folder_Treeview` as a PostBack Trigger -or-
2. Get rid of the UpdatePanel altogether -or-
3. Move the Gridview inside the UpdatePanel ContentTemplate

---

Also a [TreeView is one of several server controls that ***may not be compatible*** with an UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx):

> **The following ASP.NET controls are not compatible with partial-page updates, and are therefore not designed to work inside an UpdatePanel control:**
>
> - `TreeView` control under several conditions. One is when callbacks are enabled that are not part of an asynchronous postback. Another is when you set styles directly as control properties instead of implicitly styling the control by using a reference to CSS styles. Another is when the EnableClientScript property is false (the default is true). Another is if you change the value of the EnableClientScript property between asynchronous postbacks. For more information, see TreeView Web Server Control Overview.
> - `Menu` control when you set styles directly as control properties instead of implicitly styling the control by using a reference to CSS styles. For more information, see Menu Control Overview.
> - `FileUpload` and `HtmlInputFile` controls when they are used to upload files as part of an asynchronous postback.
> - `GridView` and `DetailsView` controls when their EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks property is set to true. The default is false.
> - `Login`, `PasswordRecovery`, `ChangePassword`, and `CreateUserWizard` controls whose contents have not been converted to editable templates.
> - The `Substitution` control.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's happened because of Update Panel only.